# Load a User Control in an Ajax WCF Service and Access Custom Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I can load a generic user control just fine in my WCF service doing the following:

```
UserControl userControl= (UserControl) new Page().LoadControl("~/UserControls/MyControl.ascx");
```

However i can't seem to find any way to do this

```
MyControl myControl=(MyControl)userControl;
```

The reason i need to do this is because my user control has a custom property, person, I need to do the following:

```
myControl.Person=new Person();
```

essentially i need to simulate:

`<%@ Reference Control="~/UserControls/MyControl.ascx" %>`

which normally goes inside asp.net page or master-pages.

any way of doing this in an Ajax Enabled WCF Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this.
A better way doing this is to simply use page methods instead of a WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be passing user controls to a service, period.  Please read up on **separation of concerns** and **dependency injection** design patterns, to find out why.

Comment: let's say have an ajax service method that returns an html anchor
|CODE|
HtmlAnchor anch=new HtmlAnchor{Href="www.domain.com"};

anch.RenderControl(writer);

return writer.ToString();
|CODE|
are you saying it's wrong to do that as well?
If not - than what is the difference between that and a user control
If yes - please explain why

Comment: Yes, I would say it is not ideal to do that as well.  Your service should return nothing but data (in most cases).  Your front-end code (e.g. presentation layer) should render the HtmlAnchor (or any other web control) after it is provided the data returned from the web service (e.g. business layer or middle tier).  Please, please, please... I beg you to research the items I mentioned in my answer, as well as n-Tier Architecture.